# Python PySerial Timeout

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyserial

I want to read data from a port. I set the timeout to 1. But when the timeout time is reached. I stop read and take all the data received so far. 
Is it possible to get a timeout error message?

Comment: A timeout error would destroy the data you did manage to receive - pyserial is certainly not going to do that by default.  You could check to see if the length of the received data is less than the amount you tried to read.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. This will work in my case :)